# How to give error on button click,if checkbox value is not selected in android and give error as "atleast select one checkbox"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a 3 checkbox named "service","repair","installation" and on the same page i have a "Next" button..what i want is,if none of the value is selected from these 3 checkboxes then on button click give error message as "Atleast select one checkbox"..

I found  a function named `isChecked`, but it din't work out for me. Is there any function like `checkbox.isNotChecked`, so that I can directly define the error part in `if` statement?

```
Button b1;
CheckBox c1,c2,c3;
EditText e1,e2;`

c1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c1);
c2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c2);
c3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.c3);
e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);
e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e2);
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


if (e1.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) { 
    e1.setError("City not entered"); e1.requestFocus(); 
} else if (e2.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) { 
    e2.setError("Name not entered"); e2.requestFocus(); 
}
});
```

If not a  single checkbox is selected give error as "Select atleast one checkbox". If at least one checkbox is selected then it can redirect to next page on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add an answer, just to be complete.

you're looking for this :

```
if(checkbox1.isChecked != true && checkbox2.isChecked != true && checkbox3.isChecked != true){ //none are checked, show your error message here 
}
```

this is the same as saying this (shorthand notation):

```
if(!checkbox1.isChecked && !checkbox2.isChecked && !checkbox3.isChecked){ //none are checked, show your error message here 
}
```

these two read:

> If checkbox1 is not checked and checkbox2 is not checked and checkbox3 is not checked

however, doing this :

```
   if(checkbox1.isChecked || checkbox2.isChecked || checkbox3.isChecked){ //here, at least one was checked 
    } else {
  //here, none of them were checked.
}
```

results in the same thing, it reads as:

> if checkbox1 is checked OR checkbox2 is checked OR checkbox3 is checked

it really just depends on which branch you want to follow.

Comment: the first answer u suggested worked perfectly..the other two you mentioned dint worked for me..!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57440712/11907360 .will you help to answer this question too..facing this issue since long..a_local_nobody

Answer (score 0):

You have to check each checkboxes state in if condition.

```
if(c1.isChecked() && c2.isChecked() && c3.isChecked() && c4.isChecked()) 
{
 //success
}
else
{
 //failed message
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work , it means that ALL 3 have to checked for it to work, which is not what OP wanted.